# How to catch subsequent API signatures?

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating an API server with user provided routes. I am stuck how can I write routes that user defined routes are dynamically handled, if the precedent route matches user's token.

I have tried two approaches, One with `:params`, but that doesn't work as desired as a user might input multiple levels of routes.

```
router.all('/api/:apikey/:fakeapi', function (req, res, next) {
  logger.debug(`API Key: ${req.params.apikey}, Requested URL: ${req.params.fakeapi}`);

  res.send(`API Key: ${req.params.apikey}, Requested URL: ${req.params.fakeapi}`);
});
```

Above code, works if route `/api/378929832/fine`, but fails when the route is something like `api/378929832/fine/with/me`.

How can I make it handle all subsequent `/xyz/xyz/xyz/...` if the precedent API signature matches it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I have come up with a hacky solution, but it's not the best way, so I have asked above question.*

I have used `*` to make it catch all after a precedent match, like below

```
router.all('/api/:apikey/*', function (req, res, next) {
  logger.debug(`API Key: ${req.params.apikey}, Requested URL: ${req.url.replace('/api/', '').replace(req.params.apikey + '/', '')}`);

  res.send(`API Key: ${req.params.apikey}, Requested URL: ${req.url.replace('/api/', '').replace(req.params.apikey + '/', '')}`);
});
```

Above code works for `http://localhost:8080/api/378929832/fine` as well for any dynamic `http://localhost:8080/api/378929832/fine/with/me` or even with `http://localhost:8080/api/378929832/fine/with/me/?redirect=http://stackoverflow.com`.

Answer (score 0):

First, just a heads up on the design of your routes - [RESTful API design](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api) is all the rage, and trying to design your API in a RESTful way can be great. It makes sense logically, and is generally expected of web services these days. Even if you're only using it internally, it can really simplify things for you by enforcing consistency across your routes, and means that it's ready-to-use if you want to open up your API to the outside world. If you're already building an API intended for outside consumption, not following best practices opens your developers up to a world of hurt!

The thing that stuck out immediately to me was the API key as part of the path. Routes are usually written as `/api/[object or resource]`, so from that perspective it doesn't make sense to throw an API key in there. More importantly, requiring the key in the URL means that every API key will be revealed in your web server's logs. You'd also have this issue if you changed it to a query string parameter, so a good option is usually having the API key or other auth token in a header (the Authorization header is commonly used with tokens).

Moving on, if you're keen to continue with the current format, you can use `router.param()`.

`router.param` takes the name of a route parameter as well as a function that will be called when a subsequent route shows up with that parameter. This means you can catch and check your API key whenever it shows up in a route without having to explicitly specify it.

For example:

```
var checkApiKey = function(req, res, next, id) {
    // `id` is the parameter that was passed
    if(!isValidApiKey(id)) return res.send("Bad");
    return next();
}

router.param("apikey",routes.checkApiKey);

router.get("/:apikey/me",routes.listMe);
router.post("/:apikey/me",routes.createMe);
```

If you have a parent router, you can move some things around so that :apikey is only specified once, at the root, and all API requests have a base of `/api/[key]/`. Functionally the same, this just means you're not duplicating the :apikey parameter for every route:

```
var apiRouter = express.Router();
apiRouter.get("/me",listMe);
apiRouter.post("/me",createMe);

parentRouter.param("apikey",checkApiKey);
parentRouter.use("/api/:apikey",apiRouter);
```

### Update

I see that your focus is on getting the requested route after the API key, which is variable according to the user. This you can accomplish easily with a parent router, like so:

```
var parseUserApiRoute = function(req, res, next) {
    // req.path contains the URL after /api/:apikey
    // e.g. For a request to /api/abcdef/this/is/my/route, req.path will be /this/is/my/route
    res.send("Path: "+req.path);
}
var checkApiKey = function () {...};

var apiRouter = express.Router();
apiRouter.get("*",parseUserApiRoute);

parentRouter.param("apikey",checkApiKey)
parentRouter.use("/api/:apikey",apiRouter);
```

Comment: @errhunter Sorry, I misunderstood what you were trying to do - you have a very interesting use case! In this case, you can still use a parent router to simplify catching the URL that the user has entered after their API key. I have updated my answer with an example. I would still suggest moving the key out of the URL for the same reasons as above.